# I need to make a horizontal menu with moving images in CSS3 and html

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a big problem, this is all my code from the site so far.. I need to make a horizontal navigation menu bar thats snapped to the top of my site with icons all along it that have a transition lying under it, containing the link (the menu button).

The transition kinda works but it doesn't push the following img away, allowing the text to be shown together with the proper icon.

CSS:

```
*                   { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; }


html, body              { width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
}


body                    { display: inline-block;
}


wrapper             { width: 100%;                          
                    background-color: #0F0;
                    margin-top: 40px;                       
}


#topsnap_nav                { width: 100%;
                    height: 40px;
                    background-color: #000;
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 0px;
}


ul                  { float: right;
}


ul li                   { list-style-type: none;
}


li                  { display: inline-block;
                    background-color: #CF0;
                    position: relative;
                    float:right;
}


li a                    { width: 0px;
                    background:red;
                    transition:width 2s;
                    -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari */
                    display: block;
                    float: left;
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    right: 0px;
                    margin-right: 40px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    height: 40px;
}



li:hover a              { width: 400px;
}


li img                  { float: right;
                    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles_main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles_fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles_nav.css">
</head> 


<body> 

<div id="topsnap_nav">

        <nav>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="images/work_images/Untitled-1.png" width="40">
                <a href="#">hi</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/work_images/Untitled-1.png" width="40">
                <a href="#">hello</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>

        </nav>

</div>


    <div id="wrapper"> 

        hi hi hi...

    </div> 

</body>
```

Comment: So the image over the link should slide to the left together displaying the link-text, is it right? more or less like in this fiddle? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/U5e39

Comment: you're welcome! :) i'll put it as an answer cause i was not sure of what you were meaning, so you can vote it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example [http://jsfiddle.net/U5e39e](http://jsfiddle.net/U5e39)

i put the transition on the list element and work with z-index

```
li { display: block;    
position: relative;
float:right;
transition:width 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari */
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
background-color: #CF0;
}


li a { width: 0px;
    background:red;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    color: blue;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

li:hover { width: 400px;
}

li:hover img{ float:left}


li img { float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```